# How can I remove a browser action badge?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using [chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText) to add a badge to my extension's browser icon that shows the number of uncompleted tasks in the user's todo list.

[image: The badge when the user has tasks]

At the moment when the user has zero tasks I end up with this:

[image: The badge when the user has zero tasks]

However what I'd prefer is to not show the badge at all when the user has zero tasks.

Here's my code:

```
setBrowserActionBadge: function(allTasks) {
  var task_count;
  task_count = allTasks.filter(function(task) {
    task.isDone === false;
  }).length;

  task_count = task_count.toString();

  if (task_count === 0) {
    task_count = '';
  }

  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
    'text': task_count
  });

  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({
    'color': '#333333'
  });

};
```

This method is run each time tasks are checked off or added, so it updates in real time.

What would be ideal is something like `chrome.browserAction.clearBadge` which I can run when the task count is 0 to remove the badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. You do want to pass an empty string however your test `if (task_count === 0)` will never be true because you are using === instead of ==. Task count is a string thus never === 0 (a number).
you can easily find this issue by using the chrome debugger. A breakpoint in that `if` would never hit so you would go hmmmm and see it.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So I'm actually compiling this from Coffeescript, and Coffeescript pretty much says 'use === always' when compiling to JavaScript. I don't suppose you know of a way I can force Coffeescript to compile to == instead?

Comment: Use `=== "0"`  to keep using that